# Invalid token error on foreach c#?

Tags: c#, android, compiler-errors

Here is the code can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
I seem to be getting the error at the foreach statements and I am getting end of file expected on the curly brackets at the bottom and even when I add a ;, it still gives me that error.

```
Activity (Label = "Songression")]   
public class results : Activity
{ public results
   {
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle);

    var cbs = this.Intent.Extras.GetBooleanArray("cbs");
    var texts = this.Intent.Extras.GetBooleanArray("texts");

    foreach (var cb in cbs)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (cb);

    }

    foreach (var text in texts)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (text);

    }


    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# this statement is invalid

```
public results
{
    //some code
}
```

And I've no idea where did you get that from.
Every member should have a separate access level modifier.